# How do I refer to all the properties of one document among many documents?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, verb-agreement

There are many documents, and each document has many properties.

I am trying to say "the properties of one of the documents" I believe that it is correct to say

> One of the documents' properties is...

But I am not sure which form of the possessive to use for 'documents'

> One of the **document's**/**documents'** properties is...

Is this the right way to phrase it?

Comment: You can't say that with just one *one*. I recommend *One property of one document is ...*

Comment: "A property of one of the documents is ..."

Comment: @StoneyB What *you* been smoking? ...  (Joey from "Friends" intonation) "One of the material's properties is pliability*, for example ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria Nope. OP explicitly states that *one of the documents* (or in your version *one of the materials*) is intended, and there needs to be a ***one of the** properties*, too, to accomodate the singular verb: *one of the properties* of *one of the documents*.

Comment: The two examples (one in the blockquote and one in 'I'm trying to say...') are inconsistent. In the first one you used the verb *to be* in singular - one of the properties... **is**, and in the second one you used plural for **the properties of one of the documents**. So to clarify: are you looking for one property of several documents or a set of properties in one document (among many other documents)?

Comment: It doesn't seem that the so-called "duplicate" thread answers the OP's question.

Comment: @StoneyB but they're trying to talk about the *propert**ies*** of one of the documents. So they need the plural verb there.

Comment: @Araucaria OP has now rewritten with *is/are* instead of *is*. We're no closer to knowing what OP actually means, but it will now accommodate the reading you propose.

Comment: "The properties of one of the documents" is/are well-known by the students."... do the students know one property or many? If many, then all the examples are wrong because they all refer to a single property.